# What specifically gets rendered with forwardRef() in React

Tags: reactjs

I have the following snippet which I got from another source. I have a main functional component, called `AgreementForm`, which needs to support Print-to-PDF functionality provided by a plugin, [React-to-Print](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-to-print). The way to do it is to "wrap" `AgreementForm` in a `forwardRef` and pass it to the next defined component after it, which is the React-to-Print component. The snippet is working, but I don't understand what it does,

My question is,

- Does `AgreementForm` ever get rendered by itself?
- If not, who defines that `PrintComponent` gets rendered at any time, **rather than** `AgreementForm` ?
- What does the expression `{(el) => (componentRef = el)}` do?

  ```
   export const AgreementForm = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
         // State vars...
         const [myVar, setMyVar] = useState(null);
         // useEffects...
         useEffect(() => { 
         }, [myVar]);
         // Render...
         return (
            <>...</>
         );

    // This is print component to wrap the print button and content.
    export default function PrintComponent(props) {
       let componentRef = useRef();

       return (
       <>
        <div>
            <ReactToPrint 
                trigger={() => <Button style={{'margin-bottom':'15px'}}>Print</Button>}
                content={() => componentRef}
            />

          {/* component to be printed */}
          <AgreementForm userInfo={props.userInfo} ref={(el) => (componentRef = el)} />
        </div>
      </>
    );
   }
  ```

Comment: So they *both* get rendered? Both the Form and the PrintComponent?

Comment: Yes, they do. Just the PrintComponent receives the references from the Form.

Comment: So I get my form rendered *twice* ? That's wrong, there should only be 1 instance.

Comment: No, it won't be rendered *twice*. `AgreementForm` is only rendered when you render `PrintComponent`...

Comment: Why? Both are defined in my file `agreementForm.js`. Who decides that the first exported functional comp is skipped?

Comment: `forwardRef` is the same as `useCallback`, it's a hook. Wrapping the function (or component) in `forwardRef` does not automatically call the anonymous callback. That is only called when you explicitly render the component.

Comment: Thanks - good to know that `forwardRef` is a hook, that explains it.

Comment: But, one more question: I refer to `<AgreementFrom>` from a parent. How does it know to render `PrintComponent`, just by virtue of it being the next exported function after the hook?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it seems that provided code sample is a combination of two samples from React-to-PDF [doc page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-to-print): Calling from class components and Calling from functional components. Take a note, that when calling from class component, `AgreementForm` should be rendered like this `<AgreementForm ref={el => (this.componentRef = el)} />` . When calling from function component, it should be used like this `<AgreementForm ref={componentRef} />`.

Code in provided example will not work as `<AgreementForm userInfo={props.userInfo} ref={(el) => (componentRef = el)} />` will assign ref (`el`) to `componentRef` variable. On next render, `let componentRef = useRef();` will reassign ref to `componentRef` variable. So `ReactToPrint` will never get ref to `AgreementForm`. It will always get `undefined/null`.

To cocrrect this, use `<AgreementForm userInfo={props.userInfo} ref={(el) => (componentRef.current = el)} />`. It is essential to assign component's ref to `.current` property of the ref variable.

And this line `content={() => componentRef}` also should be changed to `content={() => componentRef.current}`

And answers to questions:

1. `AgreementForm` is rendered when `PrintComponent` is rendered.
2. `PrintComponent` should be rendered by some higher level component for printing to work
3. As described above, line `{(el) => (componentRef = el)}` is incorrect. It should be `{(el) => (componentRef.current = el)}`. This line will assign `AgreementForm` ref to `componentRef.current`, which leter can be consumer by `ReactToPrint`

Comment: Thanks, first of all the code works, for some reason. It provides correct PDF printing. Are you saying that *AgreementForm* is not rendered by itself, and it waits for *PrintComponent* to render it? In other words, there is not a double render of *AgreementForm*? I do not call *PrintComponent* from a higher-level parent, I call *AgreementForm* from a higher-level parent, and it seems to work.

Comment: Note: I got this snippet from: https://dev.to/ebereplenty/printing-in-react-made-easy-with-react-to-print-4b3k